# "NSDate not an Objective-C object" error shows when run the application in IOS 7 in real device

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios7, nsdate

NSDate object is working for iPhone, iPad when i ran the application in real devices. But when I run the application in iPad real device than it gives `<not an Objective-C object>` error. I tried to sort out it. but couldn't.

```
- (NSString*)getDateFromJSONToStringSaveFormat:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDate *_Date = [NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *_Date = [self getDateFromJSON:dateString];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_Date];
} 

- (NSDate*)  getDateFromJSON:(NSString *)dateString
{
    // Expect date in this format "/Date(1268123281843)/"
    int startPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@"("].location+1;
    int endPos = [dateString rangeOfString:@")"].location;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(startPos,endPos-startPos);
    unsigned long long milliseconds = [[dateString substringWithRange:range] longLongValue];

    NSTimeInterval interval = milliseconds/1000;
    return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];

}
```

because of this issue i initialize the NSDate object and saw the date value. (`NSDate *_Date = [NSDate alloc] init];`) in here also gives same error? why is that? anyone faced this error ??

Comment: Step through with a debugger.  I suspect somewhere near the `millisecond` bit. Also remove the first `NSDate alloc`; it's not required.  Also you are losing the fractional part of the second by not doing `NSTimeInterval interval = (NSTimeInterval)milliseconds / 1000.0;`.

Comment: Please in the future copy the exact and complete error message and paste it into your question.  But the mismatched brackets on the first alloc/init statement would certainly confuse the compiler.  Plus, having two identically-named variables is a no-go.  Just drop that entire first line of the method.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me (once you delete the first redundant `_Date` variable).

Comment: But observe the point about using `/ 1000.0` vs `/ 1000`.  The first will get you floating-point division and fractional seconds, while the second will give integer seconds.

Comment: I didn,t use Both top lines.     NSDate *_Date = [NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *_Date = [self getDateFromJSON:dateString]; first line I already committed. I made that line to ensure for the error. However same error occured when application is run in iPad real device. :( It didn't give any compile time and run time error. I checked value after putting the break point.

Answer (score 1):

First off you can just remove this line:

```
NSDate *_Date = [NSDate alloc] init];
```

Since the next line just redeclares it, also you in the line you should remove you are missing a `[`.

```
- (NSString*)getDateFromJSONToStringSaveFormat:(NSString *)dateString
{
    // Not needed since the line after it also declares the variable.
    //NSDate *_Date = [NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDate *_Date = [self getDateFromJSON:dateString];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:_Date];
}
```